# PHP file_get_contents('php://input'); truncates JSON POST data

Tags: php, json, post, file-get-contents

The following POST will return **'{"name": "TheCustomer"}'** from file_get_contents('php://input');

```
curl -i http://localhost/api/api/application_create -d '{"name": "TheCustomer"}' -H 'X-API-KEY: {MY_USER_KEY}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -v -u {MYUSER:MYPASSWORD} -X POST
```

This POST will return **'{"name": "The'** from file_get_contents('php://input');

```
curl -i http://localhost/api/api/application_create -d '{"name": "The Customer"}' -H 'X-API-KEY: {MY_USER_KEY}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -v -u {MYUSER:MYPASSWORD} -X POST
```

Any ideas what triggers the truncation?

Comment: Is there a space after "the in the second code?

Comment: Correct, this seems to be the point at which truncation occurs. The first space inside a json attribute.